# How to modify http request headers based on user options in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on my first extension for Google Chrome. I want to add a custom header to (all) http(s) requests based on options that the user can select on the options page of my extension.

I managed the following successfully:

1. Manually add custom headers to all http requests
2. Create an options page
3. Save and restore options in chrome.storage.sync

Now I'm struggling to combine the above. Here's what I tried:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
    var demoOptions = new Array();
    var demoHeader = '';
    var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage(); // for debugging
    chrome.storage.sync.get({
    demoOption: true,
    }, function(items) {
        if(items.demoOption){
            demoOptions.push('demo-header-1');
        }
        demoHeader = demoOptions.join();
        details.requestHeaders.push({
            name: 'X-Demo-Header',
            value: demoHeader //this is not showing up in the http headers
        });
        bkg.console.log('demoHeader:' + demoHeader); //this is putting the correct value to the debugging console
        bkg.console.log(details.requestHeaders); //this is putting the headers to the debugging console, incl. x-demo-header1 and x-demo-header2 (see below)
    });

    details.requestHeaders.push({
        name: 'X-Demo-Header2',
        value: 'Demo-Header-2' //this is correctly added to the headers and included in the request
    });
    
    return { requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders };
},
{urls: [ "*://*/*" ]},['requestHeaders','blocking']);
```

Observations:

1. X-Demo-Header2 is correctly inserted (visible in Chrome header inspection and n the debigging console)
2. x-demo-header1 is **not** part of the header sent to the site, but it is visible in the debugging output
3. x-demo-header2 is in the header **before** X-Demo-Header1 in the header array in the console (see screenshot)

Assumption: function(items) to fetch my options is executed asynchronyously and requestHeaders are returned before the headers from my options are inserted.

Can I avoid this? Is there a better option to add headers based on options?

Screenshot:

[image: Debugging output of the header array]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

It currently won't work in Chrome (Feb. 15th 2021)

## Long answer

JavaScript heavily relies on the idea of asynchronous code execution. In your code you return `{ requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders }` before the event listener registered in `chrome.storage.sync.get(key, listener)` has finished. Therefore, `demo-header-1` is added too late.

That's why you need to use a Promise. There is an example in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeSendHeaders) how to do that. On that page scroll down to where it says: *"This code is exactly like the previous example, except that the listener is asynchronous, returning a Promise which is resolved with the new headers"*.

In your case the modified version of your code would look this like this:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function (details) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      chrome.storage.sync.get({ demoOption: true }, function (items) {
        if (items.demoOption) {
          details.requestHeaders.push({
            name: 'X-Demo-Header',
            value: 'demo-header-1',
          });
        }
        resolve({ requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders });
      });
    });
  },
  { urls: ['*://*/*'] },
  ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']
);
```

As you can see we now return a Promise instead of an object literal. In this Promise we wait for the read operation of `chrome.storage.sync.get` to finish. Once it's done we resolve the Promise.

This should work in browsers which support this.

### In Chrome this doesn't work because:

[There is no support in Chrome for returning a Promise from webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders since 2018](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=806283)

Unless you can find a way to load the data from `chrome.storage.sync.get` in a synchronous way you are out of luck I'm afraid.

As a last resort you can try to post a complaint in that [Chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=806283).